# Alternative to "Relational().ColumnType" in C#

Tags: relational

It is used to determine the size of the field if it is not defined before

```
foreach (var property in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes()
    .SelectMany(e => e.GetProperties()
    .Where(p => p.ClrType == typeof(string))))
    property.Relational().ColumnType = "varchar(100)";
```

[image]

**Error message:** 'IMutableProperty' does not contain a definition for 'Relational' and no accessible extension method 'Relational' accepting a first argument of type 'IMutableProperty' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 0):

Replace the **Relational().ColumnType** command with **SetColumnType()**

```
foreach (var property in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes()
    .SelectMany(e => e.GetProperties()
    .Where(p => p.ClrType == typeof(string))))
    property.SetColumnType("varchar(100)");
```

Depending on the failure check if it called the Linq library

```
using System.Linq;
```